# When is doPut() called in a servlet?

Tags: java, http, servlets

Hi I was just curious when is the doPut() method in a servlet called. I know that if the form on a jsp/html page has a "post" method then the doPost() is called otherwise if it has a "GET" then the doGet() is called.When is the doPut() called ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The doPut() method handles requests send by using the HTTP PUT method. The PUT method allows a client to store information on the server. For an example, you can use it to post an image file to the server. As the above answer says, goGet() and doPost() are in use, mostly. In my case, I use only these two, and I am getting only get requests, so I simply transfer the get request to doPost() and do my job easily.

Comment: Then they have copied that from my book, my diploma It is in NIIT Master mind series, j2ee web components-1, page number 1A.11

Comment: Thanks BalusC, Thank you letting me know. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @MaDu_LK: Don't play here and there if you are new to StackOverflow, read the above comments first.

Answer (score 8):

When an [HTTP PUT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_PUT#Request_methods) request is received, naturally.

> Can a page do a PUT request by code?

The only valid `method` attribute values of a `<form>` are `get` and `post`, [according to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission). I assume that's what you're asking.

Comment: Or put another way, if you don't know when you're expecting to receive a PUT request, that probably means you don't need to care about it.

Answer (score -2):

if you want to send some confidential values in url via form you must use the post method, If you will use the get method for the form like login the values parameters like userid and password will be visible in url and anyone can hack that thing. So better to use post method in forms. By default it will call get method.

```
in get the url is like http://url?method=methodname&userid=123&password=123

so if you use post method the url will be like this http://url/methodname.do
```